# How to optimize the hibernate lucene fetching records time

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, lucene, hibernate-search

I am doing hibernate lucene with boolean search to fetch the records from the database.Present in my table there are 250 records.I think it's not a matter for hibernate lucene to fetch.But what's happening is, it is taking 1.30 min to 2.30 minutes.

What's my flow is from my controller I am getting some search keywords and I am passing it to service and then to dao.In service layer I started the transaction.Finally Dao will return Listof records.After getting the records I am setting that list to List of XYZTableVo objects .

I don't know where exactly the time is taking whether in the lucene or in Object preparation of VO.
Following is my snippet

```
Session session = getSession();     
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    SearchFactory searchFactory = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory();
    fullTextSession
    .createIndexer(XYZTable.class)
    .typesToIndexInParallel(20)
    .batchSizeToLoadObjects(25)
    .cacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL)
    .threadsToLoadObjects(5)
    .startAndWait();
    searchFactory.optimize(CvlizerJobseeker.class);
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] { "Skills.skill" },
            new StandardAnalyzer());
    parser.setDefaultOperator(Operator.OR);
    org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = null;
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(XYZTable.class)
            .get();
    BooleanQuery boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();
    if (locationList != null) {
        if (locationList.get(2) != null) {
            boolQuery.add(qb.keyword().onField("XYZTablePersonalInfo.XYZTableAddress.postalCode")
                    .matching(locationList.get(2)).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }
        else if (locationList.get(1) != null) {
            boolQuery.add(qb.keyword().onField("XYZTablePersonalInfo.XYZTableAddress.city")
                    .matching(locationList.get(1)).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        }
    }
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(query) != true && StringUtils.isBlank(query) != true) {
        try {
            luceneQuery = parser.parse(query.toUpperCase());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            luceneQuery = parser.parse(parser.escape(query.toUpperCase()));
        }
        boolQuery.add(luceneQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }
    boolQuery.add(qb.keyword().onField("isValid").matching(false).createQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    FullTextQuery createFullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(boolQuery, XYZTable.class);
createFullTextQuery.list();
```

Comment: With _createIndexer(XYZTable.class)...startAndWait()_ you're starting the re-indexing process of the whole database. That's going to take a long time, could even take hours on a large database! You want to rebuild the index only once each time you change the index mapping or the analyzers being used, don't do it before each query!

Comment: @Sanne.Tq for the reply.I generated index at the  time of application loading .Lucene generated index successfully for the existing data.But when I am doing any modification to the existing data  through hibernate core like insertion updation etc.It is not reflecting to my search.I don't know where it is wrong.